# Pause/Resume download functionality for iPhone

Tags: iphone, download

I want to implement a download manager in iPhone. Now it appears that it iPhone SDK esp NSURLConnection does not support Pause/Resume functionality if the server does not support the Range headers.

I don't want to use external libraries like ASHTTPRequest.

Is there any way I could support resuming of an application from where it was stopped

Comment: you can cancel current connection and start it again whenever you want, but for pausing and resuming, I do not think, there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why build something from scratch that has been build before? ASIHTTPRequest can handle this sort of thing perfectly, there is no need for you to reinvent the wheel. If you do enjoy such a thing, perhaps take a peek at how they do it (it's open source you know).

Comment: I'll just check again if ASIHTTPRequest can solve what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you are referring to 'resumable downloads', I can assure you 100% it can. Used it myself for that very purpose.

Comment: Is ASIHTTPRequest still supported in iOS???I guess it has been discontinued by the developer long back.. I am looking for a solution to the question above. Any ideas?

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has indeed been discontinued (or at least development has) a short while back. It still works, and I still use it, because it is basically a wrapper on top of some very basic core functionality that will not likely break any time soon..

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't support the range headers, it won't be able to send partial data and so you won't be able to resume from where it was stopped.